# Find the last hyperlink in a string

Tags: php, regex

I would like to find the last hyperlink in a string.  The hyperlink may begin with one of the following:

http://

https://

market://

Is there a regex method in PHP to find this?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes there is a regex method to find that.

Comment: Of course there is. Is using regex the best solution? Hard to know. Can you please provide an example of the string and what you've already tried...?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this negative lookahead based regex:

```
~\b(?:https?|market)://\S+?(?!.*?\b(?:https?|market)://)~i
```

Comment: You need to make the `\S+` non-greedy. Right now this matches `http://f,http://foo`. [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/kJ3dW9/1).

Answer (score 0):

```
$regex = "/(http|https|market)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";

$text = "http://link.com some text in between https://link.com more text in between market://link.com";

if(preg_match_all($regex, $text, $url)) 
{
    echo $url[0][count($url[0])-1]; // Outputs: market://link.com
}
```

Comment: To be fair, if the string is comma delimited then [a simple explode would be better than regex here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/113243/108554)

Comment: That was just an example though. It works fine without the commas.